# Does any literate programming environment support on the fly results?

Tags: haskell, latex, markdown, literate-programming

I am currently writing lots of small reports. Most of them are just *value dumps* with some graphs and illustrative comments.

Is there a literate programming environment that let's me write my reports in an easy format (preferably markdown/latex and haskell) and then converts to some output format (preferably pdf) that contains results of the calculations done in the original file?

I know that Haskell supports literate programming but I don't think that the output (and possibly whole images) can be captured.

Comment: [How can other programming languages and tools be used to create content for TeX documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48386/5701) might be of interest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [lhs2TeX](http://www.andres-loeh.de/lhs2tex/) preprocessor supports evaluating Haskell expressions via GHCi. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

%include polycode.fmt
%options ghci

\begin{document}

Running

> fmap (+1) [1..10]

yields \eval{fmap (+1) [1..10]}.

\end{document}
```

This will produce output which contains the list `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]` in the place where the `\eval` command is in the input.

You can reference definitions from the current file. I.e., the `\eval` function works by loading the current file into `ghci` and then evaluating the expression in that context.

There's also `\perform` which does the same as `\eval`, but the output will not be seen as a piece of Haskell code, but rather as a piece of LaTeX code. So you can write Haskell functions that generate parts of your output document.

That being said, there are lots of things that could be improved about this functionality in lhs2TeX, and the implementation is quite a hack.

**EDIT:** Concluding from the comments, the goal is to include images generated by the [Chart](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart) library. Here is a proof-of-concept document that shows how to achieve this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%include polycode.fmt
%options ghci

%if style == newcode
(Stuff here will not be typeset by LaTeX, but seen by Haskell.)

> import Data.Accessor
> import Graphics.Rendering.Chart
>
> renderAndInclude :: Renderable a -> FilePath -> IO ()
> renderAndInclude r filename = do
>   renderableToPDFFile r 200 200 filename
>   putStrLn $ "\\includegraphics{" ++ filename ++ "}"

%endif

%format ^= = "\mathbin{{}^\wedge\!\!=}"

\begin{document}

The image description

> image :: Renderable ()
> image  =  toRenderable
>        $  layout1_title  ^=  "Test"
>        $  layout1_plots  ^=  [ Left (toPlot plot) ]
>        $  defaultLayout1
>   where
>     plot   =  plot_lines_values ^= [[ (x, sin x) | x <- [0, 0.01 .. 10 :: Double] ]]
>            $  defaultPlotLines

yields the following output:

\perform{renderAndInclude image "image.pdf"}.

\end{document}
```

The central helper function you have to write is something like `renderAndInclude` above that performs the actual rendering, writes the result to a file, and produces a LaTeX `\includegraphics` command that reads back the file.

Comment: That's nice :) Now the only thing that is missing is the ability to create and add images on the fly.

Comment: @Florian If you have Haskell code that can produce the image, then it can be done using `\perform`.

Comment: Ah ... so if I find a way to output something latex compatible from [Charts](http://dockerz.net/twd/HaskellCharts) i'd be done. Yay!

Comment: @Florian Yes. I've edited the answer to include more info on how you could achieve that.

Comment: Nice :) Honestly I was hoping for a way to embed the image into the produced Latex file. That way there would be no file clutter. But that is nitpicking :)

Comment: @Florian It's not possible to directly embed images in LaTeX files, except if you produce output for TikZ or similar LaTeX packages. I don't think Chart can do that.

Comment: That doesn't stop me from trying ... maybe i'll spend the weekend to try my hands on a latex backend :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't absolutely have to have Haskell, you can get the rest with [Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/) and [R](http://www.r-project.org/). You basically write a LaTeX document, with embedded R code. You can choose to include either the code, the result (including plots), or both in your final PDF output. [Knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) is a more recent extension (or simplification?) of Sweave.

Comment: I've worked with R before and can't say I like it. But then I didn't knew that it supported this kind of output.

Comment: @Florian perhaps this can change your impression about R: http://glimmer.rstudio.com/yihui/knitr/ It is live in the sense that there is an R session running behind it if you open it in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use diagrams instead of chart, then [diagrams-builder](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams) as described in [this blog post](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/creating-documents-with-embedded-diagrams/) is your friend. Works with markdown and LaTeX alike.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://code.google.com/p/nano-lp/, it supports Markdown/Multimarkdown and other lightweight markups (but also OpenOffice) and it's easy to include several files into one. With OpenOffice, you can export your resulting file to PDF, for example. Also Asciidoc is supported and TeX/LaTeX, so you can use them to produce PDF too

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being (very) late to the party. The answer comes only as a reference for future visitors to this question.

[Org-mode](http://orgmode.org) does provide a nice literate programming environment. Albeit a universe in itself, it's well worth looking into! Some more information about the way it handles code can be found in these links:

- [Org-mode manual, chapter 14](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Working-With-Source-Code)
- [Babel: Active code in Org-mode](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/)
- [Tutorial for R](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/how-to-use-Org-Babel-for-R.html)

There is ofc also support for Haskell, else this comment would be superfluous. While the format isn't Markdown, Org-mode has a very simple way of marking up things.

Comment: Sadly this requires Emacs :) (And I am a Vi guy)

Comment: Indeed, for a Vi-guy my suggestion isn't the best one :P (Unless you're willing to go [Evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil)!)

Comment: Naa ... I keep hitting the borders of usefulness with [vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) ... and I can just take so much ;)